# Report uncaught exceptions

Tags: java, android, uncaught-exception, android-anr-dialog

I want to catch the uncaught exceptions and send reports about them to my server. This is how I implement it:

```
public final class MyApplication extends Application
{
    private static Context context;
    private static Handler mainHandler;
    private static boolean isDebug;

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        Thread.currentThread().setUncaughtExceptionHandler(new UncaughtExceptionHandler()
        {
            @Override
            public void uncaughtException(final Thread thread, final Throwable ex)
            {
                new Thread()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {
                        Looper.prepare();

                        ReportUtils.sendReport(thread, ex);
                        Thread.currentThread().getUncaughtExceptionHandler().uncaughtException(thread, ex);
                        Looper.loop();
                        Looper.myLooper().quit();
                    }
                }.start();
            }
        });

        context = getApplicationContext();
        mainHandler = new Handler();
        isDebug = (0 != (getApplicationInfo().flags &= ApplicationInfo.FLAG_DEBUGGABLE));
    }

    @Override
    public void onTerminate(){}

    public static Context getAppContext()
    {
        return context;
    }

    public static boolean isDebugMode()
    {
        return isDebug;
    }

    public static Handler getMainHandler()
    {
        return mainHandler;
    }
}
```

Is it the right way to implement it? Any other alternative?

Comment: Personally, I'd use ACRA as the starting point, customizing it to speak to my back-end system (or adjust the back-end system to be ACRA-ready).

Comment: Ignore my previous comment, didn't realize you were on android. However, you should always prefer an `ExecutorService` over creating new `Thread`s on your own

Comment: @ColinMorelli Creating a simple thread is enough for me and no need for managing a thread pool or anything that `ExecutorSerice` gives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing this yourself, use a service already setup to do it.

Acra is one, and can upload your crash reports to a Google Docs spreadsheet.

Bugsense is another. It has free accounts and paid accounts.

Crashlytics is rather new to android but is completely free, so I recommend it. It's really simple to setup.